# root directory permission issue cocoa app to run scripts in mac os 10.7

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, root

Team,

I'm new to MAC OS Cocoa application developement.
I'm developing a cocoa application, kind of utility application.
In my application I'm executing few commands like "mkdir", "cp", "rm"
Im executing the above commands from objective c using system command. As example shown below.

```
system("mkdir tempDir");
```

While running this application from xcode it is running fine and created all folders.
when i run by double clicking on the .app file in Mac OS X 10.7, the directory is not created and exited with error code 256. I noticed that while launch the application from .app file directly it is running from root directory i.e. macintosh drive.

Then I have changed the Macintosh's permission, allowing read&write permission for everyone. I did this in "GetInfo" section. By doing this allowed the application to create directories while running from .app.

Kindly help me to solve this permission problem from my application itself.

Answer (score 0):

If permissions are ok, then its sounds like you may not be getting a proper shell environment.  There are Cocoa equivalents for many simple commands like mkdir, but if you prefer the command line, I'd suggest using the NSTask object model which I've had very good luck with.  Here is my own adaptation of a fairly common pattern for you to try.

```
-(NSString *) runThisCmd:(NSString *) runString withArgs:(NSArray *)runArgs  {

//this method of calling NSTask is designed for small quick commands that return
//a small amount of data to the command line

NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:runString];
[task setArguments:runArgs];
[task setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];
[task setStandardInput: [NSPipe pipe]];
[task setStandardError: [task standardOutput]];
[task launch];

NSData *stdOuput = [[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];

[task waitUntilExit];  

if ([task terminationStatus] == 0) {

    //scriptSuccess = YES;
}
else {

    //scriptSuccess = NO;
}

NSString *outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stdOuput encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return outputString;

}
```

call it like this:

```
NSString *runCmd = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"/bin/bash"];
NSArray *runArgs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-c",@"mkdir",@"/tmp/newdir",nil];

//update proper label
NSString *output;
output =  [self runThisCmd:runCmd withArgs:runArgs];
```

Note: you can adapt this approach to act just like the system() command if you use the [task termination] logic and drop the return strings.  Even if you don't need it, the output can be helpful in troubleshooting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem as you, and thought I might as well share the solution. You are writing data to the wrong directory. See [this page](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/finding-or-creating-application-support.html):

> On the Mac, the correct location to store persistent user-related files for your application is in a directory with the same name as your application in the Application Support directory for the current user.

The page I linked above shows you how to create a directory for your data in Application Support and find it in your code. Doing this solved all my permissions problems.